# Asp.net MVC 4 Session getting expired in `Inproc` before specified time in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session, web-config

I have this below setting in my `web.config` file for setting `session`

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="90" />

<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name="auth_cookie" 
defaultUrl="~/Admin/Index" timeout="2880" protection="Encryption"
slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="AutoDetect" />
```

Basically with the above settings the session should not get expired for **90 minutes** is my understanding but once I login, within a minute or so, the session will get expired and `Logout` action will be called!

What is that I am doing wrong here? Does `timeout` in `forms` has any impact on this `sessionState` timeout? Any other settings do I need to do?

**Please Note : I have been through many links and I haven't found any relevant solution for my problem which made me to post this question here! Feel free to ask more details if you need**

Comment: I just want to add that there is another important timeout setting that exist in IIS at the application pool level. IIS will restart the pool after the specified idle timout has reached, so to make the allocated resources free. You should make sure this pool idle timeout is always greater than the above two mentioned timeouts,

Comment: Did you chk the IIS settings??

Comment: @too_cool. I have hosted my site in `plesk` shared hosting and I am not finding that particular option under `ASP.net Settings` But there is an option of `SessionTimeOut` which is same as in `web.config`

Comment: that's Little complected i never used `plesk`.. :) Still did you try removing timeout in `sessionState` and form i.e. setting it to default did it behave the same Way.? @Guruprasad.

Comment: Nope!! Will try that once too @too_cool

Comment: One more thing how are you creating your `Auth-ticket`?? @guruprasad

Comment: @too_cool Not working either!! :(

Comment: @too_cool I am creating `auth_ticket` like this - > `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userr.Email, false);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, isPersistent);

    if (!isPersistent)
    {
        //this is because if it was not set then it got 
        //automatically set to expire next year even if 
        //the cookie was not set as persistent
        authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);//just for try added 15
    }

    Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

and Remove the `cookieless` from webconfig..
It should work i guess.. :)

Comment: where you want me to put this code? in Login Action method?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I guess previously where ever you are creating `auth_ticket` in that place.

Comment: Alright @too_cool!! I'll try this and will let you know for sure by the 10:00 PM IST as I have to go back home and then implement this! Thanks for your time..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Cheers!! waiting...and meanwhile will try to come up with different solutions...

Comment: @too_cool..I had the same setting in my file but still the issue exists.. :(

Comment: @GuruprasadRao As this doesn't work out i did some googleing and got one more solution to this(not solution just another Try may be) that you shoud try generate a `machine Key` and put it on the `web-config`..this did work for some people who faced the same issue. :)

Comment: Yea I have `machinekey` added too!! :) but I am not sure how it will be useful to maintain `session`!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i also doesn't know exactly how but it did the trick for some..as u have already added it How did you generate the Key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82778/discussion-between-too-cool-and-guruprasad-rao).